# Nebula: CalendarCombo. How to setDate()?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, nebula

Successefully created **CalendarCombo**, but all my attempts to set date for it ruined. All the time i get only blank field.

Below the fragment of my code:

```
cComboStart = new CalendarCombo(shlEngineConfigurationHelper, SWT.READ_ONLY);
System.out.println("----- trying to set START: " + fromDate.toString());
cComboStart.setBounds(242, 607, 113, 101);
cComboStart.setData(fromDate);
```

During execution i got in console proper Date for setting, but unfortunately... only blank CalendarCombo i get.

In console:

```
----- trying to set START: Sun Dec 15 00:00:00 EET 2013
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet you are calling `Widget.setData(Object)`. I think you meant `CalendarCombo.setDate(Calendar)` or `CalendarCombo.setDate(Date)` instead.
If you changed the code like this, it should work:

```
cComboStart.setDate(fromDate);
```

Comment: Thanks! It's amazing how your eye is sharp! Just one character! Thanks a lot!